# subtraction between unsigned values - unexpected result

Tags: c++, c

I have two variables (`test1` and `test2`), both unsigned.
I need to check which of them is bigger.

I'm trying to understand what happens if overflow occurs.

My first test was done with uint8_t (**char**) data type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t test1 = 0;
    printf("test1 = %d\n", test1);

    uint8_t test2 = pow(2, 8 * sizeof(test1)) - 1; //max holdable value of uint8_t
    printf("test2 = %d\n", test2);

    uint8_t test3 = test1 - test2;
    printf("test1 - test2 = %d\n", test3);

    if ((test1 - test2) == 0)
        printf("test1 == test2\n");
    if ((test1 - test2) > 0)
        printf("test1 > test2\n");
    if ((test1 - test2) < 0)
        printf("test1 < test2\n");

    if (test3 == 0)
        printf("test1 == test2\n");
    if (test3 > 0)
        printf("test1 > test2\n");
    if (test3 < 0)
        printf("test1 < test2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
test1 = 0                                                                                                                                                       
test2 = 255                                                                                                                                                     
test1 - test2 = 1                                                                                                                                               
test1 < test2                                                                                                                                                   
test1 > test2
```

What? Making the substraction and save it in a variable, then checking it, is **different from** checking the substraction on the fly?

My second test was done with uint32_t (**long**) data type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t test1 = 0;
    printf("test1 = %d\n", test1);

    uint32_t test2 = pow(2, 8 * sizeof(test1)) - 1; //max holdable value of uint32_t
    printf("test2 = %lu\n", test2);

    uint32_t test3 = test1 - test2;
    printf("test1 - test2 = %d\n", test3);

    if ((test1 - test2) == 0)
        printf("test1 == test2\n");
    if ((test1 - test2) > 0)
        printf("test1 > test2\n");
    if ((test1 - test2) < 0)
        printf("test1 < test2\n");

    if (test3 == 0)
        printf("test1 == test2\n");
    if (test3 > 0)
        printf("test1 > test2\n");
    if (test3 < 0)
        printf("test1 < test2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
test1 = 0                                                                                                                                                       
test2 = 4294967295                                                                                                                                              
test1 - test2 = 1                                                                                                                                               
test1 > test2                                                                                                                                                   
test1 > test2
```

What??? Now making the substraction and saving it in a variable, then check it, is **the same as** checking the substraction on the fly?

**SO**
I was expecting that substraction between unsigned values (without an explicit cast) ALWAYS returns a value >= 0.
But doing the substraction inside the IF leads to unexpected results.

Now I'm confused.
Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: At 3rd line in body of main: `uint8_t test2 = pow(2, 8 * sizeof(test1)) - 1;` this is not really sensible, if you take 2 to the power `8 * sizeof(test1)`, that is going to overflow a `uint8_t` and obtain the value zero. Since it is unsigned, overflow always has well-defined values. So instead of writing this, you should instead write `-1`, for clarity.

Comment: You are making it very hard work - do you think this question could be simplified to just assignment of test 1 and test 2 then examples of expressions that yield the result you expect of don't expect?  There seems to be a large amount of superfluous code to wade through here.

Comment: @ChrisBeck : or `uint8_t test1 =  ~0;` rather then assigning a negative value to an unsigned type, or better still use `UCHAR_MAX` or `std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()`

Comment: @user2104739: You've got a lot of other problems going on here. Especially, using `%d` with an `unsigned int` is not okay. And you are also not compiling with warnings on apparently. If you had done this, the compiler would explain a lot of these problems for you. When you mix signed and unsigned integers, the compiler can do surprising things, and in this case, and if you end up with `signed`... Comparing signed with unsigned... is bad, you should be taking steps to ensure the `0` literal has the right type, `static_cast` results of `test1-test2` and such, to really explore this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of **type promotion**, your `uint8` will be promoted to platform-based `int`, which is likely to be greater than 8-bit (usually 32-bit) in most of nowadays' Computer.

this line:

```
if ((test1 - test2) < 0)
```

if equivalent to

```
if ((int)((int)test1 - (int)test2) < 0) = -255 < 0
```

which is true.

However, for this line,

```
uint8_t test3 = test1 - test2;
```

it is equivalent to

```
uint8_t test3 = (uint8_t)((int)test1 - (int)test2); //(uint8_t)(-255) = 1!!;
```

So both `test1 - test2 < 0` and `test3 > 0` are (welcome to computer's world!) correct!

That explains your result.

But for `uint32`, because it is of "higher" rank than native `int`, so it is not "promoted" and stays as `uint32` all the time, or in other words

this line:

```
if ((test1 - test2) > 0)
```

if equivalent to

```
if ((uint32_t)((uint32_t)test1 - (uint32_t)test2) > 0) = large positive number > 0
```

and this line

```
uint32_t test3 = test1 - test2;
```

is equivalent to

```
uint32_t test3 = (uint32_t)test1 - (uint32_t)test2; //also large positive number
```

thus you have both `test1 - test2 > 0` and `test3 > 0`.

So, in your two cases, both can only be correct if running on 8-bit machine. Or, suppose in the future, native `int` is 64-bit, then both cases will be correct too...

Comment: In the first example after promotion the expression is `-255 < 0`

Comment: I like the @Clifford answer but I choose that one because it has a good example based on my test code. Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: Even on an 8 bit machine you won't get the same result as the minimum size of an `int` is 16 bit.

Comment: @user2104749 : No need to explain your preference - your question, whatever works for you.  I deliberately went for brief.

Answer (score 9):

The somewhat arcane [type promotion rules](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html) apply.  In the first example where the operands are `uint8_t`, for the expression:

```
test1 - test2
```

both operands are implicitly promoted to `int` *before* subtraction, and the expression itself has type `int`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is also incorrect.   The "arcane type promotion rules" don't actually apply to `unsigned char` or to `unsigned` 8-bit types.  This actually a case where the caveat at the bottom of the supplied link "Unfortunately, this is not a precise statement of these rules" is relevant.   Math operations on unsigned types use modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @Peter : As I said, they are arcane, and I would advise to expect the unexpected, and never to use char or short types as arithmetic objects, and to avoid mixed signed and unsigned expressions.  That said, I am not convinced that you are correct; from C99 6.3.1.1 : *"If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int."*.  So while it is true that modulo arithmetic occurs on unsigned types, by the time the `-` operator is evaluated, the operands are no longer unsigned.